# How to dynamically set date in WindowsStoreProxy.xml

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am going through some tutorials on how to enable trial version for windows phone 8.1 apps but I have a question which I am not able to find answer of anywhere,

How to set (current date of app installation) + 30 days as expiration date.
It is being referred to always as hard-coded dates like `<ExpirationDate>2015-10-30T00:00:00.00Z</ExpirationDate>`. Or does the windows store automatically put it with every app installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**

> does the windows store automatically put it with every app installation.

Yes, but you need to provide `LicenseDuration`.

**More on Windows Phone App Trial Experience**

To implement a trial experience in your Windows Phone app you can include the `LicenseDuration` attribute, if the `ProductType` is `Durable`. This indicates the number of days for which the license will be valid after the item has been purchased. The expiration date of the new license created by a product purchase is the purchase date plus the license duration.  [LicenseDuration is ignored for consumable in-app products.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator)

Whereas you can [implement a trial experience in your Windows Phone app.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286402%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: what if I need it to be a installation date + 30 days rather than purchase date + 30 days. Is it same?

Comment: `installation date` and `purchase date` are same. Purchase Date is when user try to install an app from Store. So its just the naming whereas the feature is one and the same.